# How to Set BaseAdapter for RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, baseadapter

Whenever I need to implement a custom `ListView` or `GridView` . I always use a `BaseAdapter` class like this:

```
public class CustomFlowerGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private HashMap<String, String> mFlowerFeed = new HashMap<>();

private Context mContext;
static LayoutInflater mFlowerInflater = null;

CustomFlowerGridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {

    super();
    this.mContext = context;
    MainActivity.flowerArrayFeedList = data;
    mFlowerInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return MainActivity.flowerArrayFeedList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return MainActivity.flowerArrayFeedList.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    final ViewHolder holder;

    if(view == null){

        view = mFlowerInflater.inflate(R.layout.flower_grid_row, viewGroup, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mainGridName);

        view.setTag(holder);
        mFlowerFeed = MainActivity.flowerArrayFeedList.get(i);
        mFlowerImage = MainActivity.flowerArrayImageList.get(i);

    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        mFlowerFeed = MainActivity.flowerArrayFeedList.get(i);
        mFlowerImage = MainActivity.flowerArrayImageList.get(i);

    }

    holder.name.setText(mFlowerFeed.get("name"));

    return view;
}

private class ViewHolder {

    TextView name

 }
}
```

However, now I'm trying to implement a `Horizontal ListView`. After doing some research, I found that the "correct" way to implement a Horizontal ListView is to use a `RecyclerView`. This is what I have in my `MainActivity`

```
CustomFlowerGridViewAdapter customFlowerGridViewAdapter = new CustomFlowerGridViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, flowerArrayFeedList);
    flowersGrid.setAdapter(customFlowerGridViewAdapter);
```

The problem is when I try set the adapter.

[image]

How do I set a BaseAdapter to a RecyclerView?

Comment: any luck @grant?

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque Although your solution is probably best practice, my solution was simple, quick and effective.

Comment: No problem, the solution is personal. If the one you've found works for you then it's the right solution :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't. RecylerViews accept another kind of adapter, different from the one in ListView. A simple example of adapter with a list of strings:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private String[] mDataset;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextView;
        public ViewHolder(TextView v) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = v;
        }
    }

   public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        TextView v = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);
        ...
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position]);

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

This one can be found in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#java). So you need to implement a ViewHolder class that and your adapter will use. Your adapter needs to extend RecyclerView.Adapter.

To set the list to be horizontal you need to set a LinearLayourManager in your recycler view with the Horizontal property set.

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(dataset);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: gonna attempt this with the help of your code, if works out. Will accept as best Answer, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your `CustomFlowerGridViewAdapter` needs to extend `RecyclerView.Adapter`.  You will also need to change some of your methods in your adapter well. With `RecyclerView`, the layout as a grid will be controlled by a `GridLayoutManager` which you can set outside of your adapter.

Comment: It's impossible to use a BaseAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple solution. No need to deal with `RecyclerViews`

[Rotate-Layout-Wrapper](https://github.com/rongi/rotate-layout)

Then, inside the wrapper, specify the angle to 90.

```
com.github.rongi.rotate_layout.layout.RotateLayout
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/mainFlowersGridL"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mainFlowersHeading"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            app:angle="90"> <!-- Specify rotate angle here -->

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/mainFlowersGrid"
                android:layout_below="@+id/mainFlowersHeading"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </GridView>
        </com.github.rongi.rotate_layout.layout.RotateLayout>
```

Then, in your custom element xml file. Specify the Layout to -90.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
class RVAdapterWrapper(var orgAdapter: BaseAdapter) : Adapter<RVAdapterWrapper.RVWrapperVH>() {
    
        private var parent: ViewGroup? = null
    
    
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RVWrapperVH {
            this.parent = parent
            val view = orgAdapter.getView(0, null, parent);
            return RVWrapperVH(view)
        }
    
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RVWrapperVH, position: Int) {
            orgAdapter.getView(position, holder.itemView, parent)
        }
    
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return orgAdapter.count
        }
        
        class RVWrapperVH(var view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
    }
```

Comment: please brief the answer little bit

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31298899)